# Salesforce to salesforce partnernetworkrecordcreation delete not possible?

Tags: community, salesforce2salesforce

we are using salesforce to salesforce to share record to another ORg. we know all the connection and opertaion. Those are working fine. the object called 'Partnernetworkrecordconnection' hold s the reference of all the shared record. when we try to delete we got an message saying that the DML not allowed. My concern is

1. If we cant delete the reference then will that count againt the storage.?
2. Is there any limit for this particular object.
3. If we can't delete, can i fetch one year old shared data if still connection is active.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a PNRC doesn’t actually delete it

If you go into Developer Console and query on `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection`, then delete selected records through the DC user interface, the records don’t actually delete, they have their status changed to Inactive.